# Are there any utilities to extract binary data from SQL Server?

Tags: sql-server

Are there any utilities available that allow you to bulk extract binary data from a SQL Server table?

For example, I have a number of Word documents stored in a table and I would like to extract all of these documents into files.

I know could do this by writing some .NET code, but I only need to do it once.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, You can use bcp utility:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa174646(SQL.80).aspx

And this simple stored procedure:

http://jahaines.blogspot.com/2009/10/exporting-binary-files-to-file-system.html

Comment: Yep, unfortunately there is no simple one line solution until You use some third party tools or such way. I hope this helps :)

Comment: Thanks this did help, when I did a google search on BCP I came accross another utility, TextCopy.exe (part of the SQL 2000 tools) And knocked up a batch script to export the docuuments. But it looks like the link you provided would do the same thing. Thanks!

Comment: @RafalZiolkowski Well, how about third party tools? Is there anything commercial I don't have to spend hours on to get such a job done?

Comment: @John - IMHO you'll have to spend hours anyway... either you do it using BCP/sp or you'll be configuring SSIS or writing code or using some other solution - it's all the same.

Comment: @RafalZiolkowski I ended up writing code. Your right, in our universe. In my fantasy though their is this parallel dimension in which I could open up a graphical tool and click "export wizard" to export a bunch of documents I have in a column. I know, it's a ridiculous demand as such a feature would surely require many dozens of man-years to implement. It's not a simple as, and as important as, for example, exporting data to a ms-word-table. Because I know 3 tools to do that with. Welcome to the world of databases, where simple stuff is difficult - and vice versa. Sorry for the rant.

Comment: @John I'm not surprised - I was there 2 years ago. Decided to write own code. I've tried SSIS, Tivoli Directory Integrator and found either configuration is so complex (TDI) or basic error checking is so generic (SSIS) that I would have to spend a lot of time on implementing (clicking) it one by one so I decided to write own ETL which suits exactly my needs.

Answer (score 0):

This tool may be helpful. this tool is based on bcp command
https://sqlserverrider.wordpress.com/2014/04/22/graphical-interface-for-bcp-sql-server-utility-software/