# Storing Microsoft Word 97 documents in SQL Server column

Tags: c#, sql-server, vb.net, visual-studio, ms-word

I have this database with a table which has the the following but I have no way to decypher it

```
DATA,        TYPE,            FILE TYPE, SIZE,  DOC TYPE
0x15234324 , Word.Document.8 ,DOC,       19968, WORD.DOCUMENT.8
```

The field seems to contain a word document stored in a SQL Server `IMAGE` column

Has anyone come across this before or a way to extract this data in a readable format?

So far I have tried using PHP to extract the file and write it to a word document but not had much luck.

**UPDATE:** I now have Visual Studio Express and would like a way to extract this data and save to a word document

**UPDATE2:** This is what I have in VB sofar

```
Imports System.Data.SqlClient
Imports System.IO


Public Class Form1

    Private Shared Function RetrieveFile(ByVal filename As String) As Byte()
        Dim connection As New SqlConnection("Server=sqlsrv;database=database;Trusted_Connection=Yes;")
        Dim command As New SqlCommand("select data from objects where object_ref in (select data from parts where object_ref =239804)", connection)
        command.Parameters.AddWithValue("test", filename)
        connection.Open()
        Dim reader As SqlDataReader = command.ExecuteReader(System.Data.CommandBehavior.SequentialAccess)
        reader.Read()
        Dim memory As New MemoryStream()
        Dim startIndex As Long = 0
        Const ChunkSize As Integer = 256
        While True
            Dim buffer As Byte() = New Byte(ChunkSize - 1) {}
            Dim retrievedBytes As Long = reader.GetBytes(1, startIndex, buffer, 0, ChunkSize)
            memory.Write(buffer, 0, CInt(retrievedBytes))
            startIndex += retrievedBytes
            If retrievedBytes <> ChunkSize Then
                Exit While
            End If
        End While
        connection.Close()
        Dim data As Byte() = memory.ToArray()
        memory.Dispose()
        Return data


    End Function


    Private Sub Button2_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button2.Click
        Dim saveFileDialog1 As New SaveFileDialog()
        saveFileDialog1.Filter = "Doc File|*.doc"
        saveFileDialog1.Title = "Save an doc File"
        saveFileDialog1.ShowDialog()

        If saveFileDialog1.FileName <> "" Then
            Dim fs As New System.IO.FileStream(saveFileDialog1.FileName, System.IO.FileMode.Create, System.IO.FileAccess.Write)
            Dim data As Byte() = RetrieveFile("test.doc")
            fs.Write(data, 0, data.Length)
            fs.Flush()
            fs.Close()
        End If
    End Sub




End Class
```

Comment: You could probably just store the bytes contained in `DATA` into the file system and then open that file with MS Word.

Comment: Cool - how would extract this data from the SQL server though? as the string seams to be to short in the SQL managment query results window

Comment: Yes, SSMS will always truncate to a max. length - you'll need to use some code to grab it from within SQL Server. See this [other SO question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2818557/are-there-any-utilities-to-extract-binary-data-from-sql-server) on a similar topic - maybe that'll help you

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I wrote a VBS script to pull data out of sharepoint blobs a while back, here's a generic version of it:

```
Const adOpenKeyset                  = 1
Const adLockOptimistic              = 3
Const adTypeBinary                  = 1
Const adSaveCreateOverWrite         = 2

strSQLServer = "YOURSERVER"
strSQLDatabase = "YOURDB"
strRecordID = "123"
strTempFileName = "c:\output.doc"

Set objConn = CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")
Set objRS = CreateObject("ADODB.RecordSet")
Set objStream = CreateObject("ADODB.Stream")

objConn.Open "Provider=SQLOLEDB;data Source=" & strSQLServer & ";Initial Catalog=" & strSQLDatabase & "; Trusted_Connection=yes;"
objRS.Open "Select * from AllDocStreams WHERE ID='" & strRecordID & "'", objConn, adOpenKeyset, adLockOptimistic

objStream.Type = adTypeBinary
objStream.Open
objStream.Write objRS.Fields("Content").Value
objStream.SaveToFile strTempFileName, adSaveCreateOverWrite

objRS.Close
objConn.Close
```

Comment: I tried the above and im getting a converter error in word then the following text - ÿÿÿÿDocument Word.Document.8 Word.Document.8 æ ÐÏ à¡± á > þÿ - Looks like output is wrong

Comment: I tested this with a Word 2007 document stored in a Sharepoint 2007 database this morning and it seemed to work OK.

Answer (score 2):

C# code:

```
connection.Open();
SqlCommand command1 = new SqlCommand("select DATA from TABLE where ...", connection);
byte[] img = (byte[])command1.ExecuteScalar();
File.WriteAllBytes("your_path/word.doc", img);
```

That should be the logic. Write something similar in any language you know. It shouldn't be hard in PHP or whatever you are using.

Comment: See update 2 above This is the code I have ripped sofar and im getting an index out of bounds ! any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

take a look at this thread.

http://www.sqlteam.com/forums/topic.asp?TOPIC_ID=101754

The guy does it using the SCRIPTING.FILESYSTEMOBJECT to extract the contents from an IMAGE column and write it to a file.

read down through the comments.

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this, replace the "some" values with your own:

```
declare @doc varbinary(max), @ObjectToken int

select @doc = (select data from yourTable were someID = @idThatYouWant)

set @FileName = '\someFolder\' + 'someFilename.doc'

print 'Processing: ' + isnull(@FileName, 'null')

exec sp_oacreate 'ADODB.Stream', @objecttoken output
exec sp_oasetproperty @objecttoken, 'type', 1
exec sp_oamethod @objecttoken, 'open'
exec sp_oamethod @objecttoken, 'write', null, @doc
exec sp_oamethod @objecttoken, 'savetofile', null, @FileName, 2
exec sp_oamethod @objecttoken, 'close'
exec sp_oadestroy @objecttoken
```

Comment: this works and the file writes out but it dosnt open in word getting a converter error in word then the following text - ÿÿÿÿDocument Word.Document.8 Word.Document.8 æ ÐÏ à¡± á > þÿ - Looks like output is wrong

Answer (score 0):

I think you will get an IndexOutOfRangeException in the following line of your code:

```
 Dim retrievedBytes As Long = reader.GetBytes(1, startIndex, buffer, 0, ChunkSize)
```

because the index of the first param is 0 not 1

anyway I suggest you use a method like the one Klark has suggested, which is simpler and more readable.